# Two date stamps, echo something for every day in between

Tags: php

Okay say I have two timestamps saved in database in the format yyyymmdd, a start date and end date.

say these are my start and end dates: 20110618-20110630

How could i make it echo 20110618, 20110619, 20110620 etc all the way to 20110630?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Will return the number of days between the two dates passed in
function count_days( $a, $b ) {
    // First we need to break these dates into their constituent parts:
    $gd_a = getdate( $a );
    $gd_b = getdate( $b );

    // Now recreate these timestamps, based upon noon on each day
    // The specific time doesn't matter but it must be the same each day
    $a_new = mktime( 12, 0, 0, $gd_a['mon'], $gd_a['mday'], $gd_a['year'] );
    $b_new = mktime( 12, 0, 0, $gd_b['mon'], $gd_b['mday'], $gd_b['year'] );

    // Subtract these two numbers and divide by the number of seconds in a
    //  day. Round the result since crossing over a daylight savings time
    //  barrier will cause this time to be off by an hour or two.
    return round( abs( $a_new - $b_new ) / 86400 );
}

// Prepare a few dates
$date1 = strtotime( '20110618' );
$date2 = strtotime( '20110630' );

// Calculate the differences, they should be 43 & 11353
echo "<p>There are ", count_days( $date1, $date2 ), " days.</p>\n";
$days = count_days($date1, $date2);
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    echo date('Ymd', $date1+(86400*$i));
}
```

Using function from: [Get number of days between two dates](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=2223).

Comment: This method is really convoluted - use [DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319388/two-date-stamps-echo-something-for-every-day-in-between/6319445#6319445)

Answer (score 2):

This should print all of the dates for you on PHP 5.3

```
$start = '20110618';
$end = '20110630';

$date = new DateTime($start);
$end = new DateTime($end)->getTimestamp();

while ($date->getTimestamp() <= $end) {
    echo $date->format('Ymd');
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a PHP datetime object, so the following would be the persudo code

```
//Convert the 2 dates to a php datetime object
//Get the number of days differance inbetween
//For each day, 
      //create a new datetime object, N days after the youngest object
      //Echo the reasult out
```

Comment: Those are pseudo-comments, I believe. If such a thing exists. ;)

Comment: Haha, sorry bad habit. I tend to just do this, copy paste it, and type the actual code with it

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like:
(edited to include actual php loop)

```
$date = new DateTime('20110618');
do {
    $d = $date->format('Ymd') . "\n";
    echo $d;
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
} while ($d < 20110630);
```